# deactivateApp(MainActivity) is undefined for the type AppEventsLogger

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK to create a simple Facebook log in application. I created a new app and added Facebook SDK in library. According to instruction given by Facebook i have added this code :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
```

but along with this i need to add deactivation code as well, so i added this code :

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }
```

Here 'AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);' is showing error "**The method deactivateApp(MainActivity) is undefined for the type AppEventsLogger**". Can any one help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `initialize` Facebook SDK before you can use it. Add a call to `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` from `onCreate` in Activity or Application:

```
// Add this to the header of your file:
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;

// Updated your class body:
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
    // especially, if you're using Facebook UI elements.
}
```

Add a `uses-permission` element to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Add a `meta-data` element to the `application` element:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    ...
</application>
```

**Using Login or Share**

To use Facebook Login or Share, also add the `FacebookActivity` to the manifest:

```
<activity 
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
      android:configChanges=
             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Check out this link [Getting Started Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)